# Hue configuration error -/etc/hue/conf.empty - Potential misconfiguration detected

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, hue, cloudera-quickstart-vm

[image: Configuration files located in /etc/hue/conf.empty]

Hi Experts,

I'm newbie to Hadoop , linux environment and Cloudera. I installed cloudera vm 5.7 on my machine and imported mysql data to hdfs using SQOOP. I'm trying to execute to some queries against this data using impala. So, I tried launching HUE. When I launched I could see there is some misconfiguration error.

Error:

**Potential misconfiguration detected. Fix and restart Hue.**

**Steps I have taken to troubleshoot this issue**

1)I restarted HUE using below command:

sudo service hue stop

sudo service hue start

2) I tried looking at following directory file ./etc/hue - I could see there are two config folder. One is config and other on config.empty. I couldn't figure out the problem.

But Still I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: You do know you don't need Hue to run Impala queries, right?

Comment: Yes, Am I trying to access the tools via HUE.Now,I'm struck with it. Insteadof finding a work around solution.I like to fix the issue.

Comment: I'm just saying if impala is the end goal here, then the terminal should work. Otherwise, I imagine when you downloaded the quickstart VM hue worked fine and you needed to start it from Cloudera Manager

Comment: Yes I tried launching Cloudera Manager.But it recursively refreshing the page again and again. I'm learning these tools to enhance my knowledge. So, I want to fix this issue rather finding a work around solution.

Comment: Kindly take a look at the URL http://i.stack.imgur.com/BH1C9.jpg Looking for an assist.

Answer (score 1):

check out! your internet access from docker/VM, and after lots of messing around trying to figure out why the vmWare Bridge adapter wasn't working, I found my problem was docker. So you have to increase docker memory from UI or command ,mine was 2 I increased to 8 but 4 is ok  [image: docker UI]

Answer (score 0):

1. Stop **hue** :

   ```
    sudo service hue stop
   ```
2. Restart **HBASE** :

   ```
    sudo service hbase-thrift stop;
    sudo service hbase-thrift start;
   ```
3. Restart **Hive**  :

   ```
    sudo service hive-server2 stop
    sudo service hive-server2 start
   ```
4. Start **hue**

   ```
    sudo service hue start
   ```
5. Open, `http://quickstart.cloudera:8888/about/` : it should work like a charm